# Update multiple rows using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have these tables and values:

```
Table1
------------------------
ID | Value
------------------------
2 | asdf
4 | fdsa
5 | aaaa


Table2
------------------------
ID | Value
------------------------
2 | bbbb
4 | bbbb
5 | bbbb
```

I want to update all the values in Table2 using the values in Table1 with their respective ID's.

Is there a way to do that with a simple SQL query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server UPDATE from SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Run a select to make sure it is what you want

```
SELECT t1.value AS NEWVALUEFROMTABLE1,t2.value AS OLDVALUETABLE2,*
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Update

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Value = t1.Value
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Also, consider using `BEGIN TRAN` so you can roll it back if needed, but make sure you `COMMIT` it when you are satisfied.

Comment: the above solution works like a charm, we can even add 'where' clause at the end on " '`join` & `on`" clause  make sure to `rollback transaction tx1`

Answer (score 10):

If you have ids in both tables, the following works:

```
update table2
    set value = (select value from table1 where table1.id = table2.id)
```

Perhaps a better approach is a join:

```
update table2
    set value = table1.value
    from table1
    where table1.id = table2.id
```

Note that this syntax works in SQL Server but may be different in other databases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use alias to improve the query:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.Value = t2.Value
  FROM table1 AS t1
         INNER JOIN 
       table2 AS t2
         ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

None of above answers worked for me in **MySQL**, the following query worked though:

```
UPDATE
    Table1 t1
    JOIN
    Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID 
SET
    t1.value =t2.value
WHERE
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this one on MySQL, MS Access and SQL Server. The id fields are the fields on wich the tables coincide, not necesarily the primary index.

```
UPDATE DestTable INNER JOIN SourceTable ON DestTable.idField = SourceTable.idField SET DestTable.Field1 = SourceTable.Field1, DestTable.Field2 = SourceTable.Field2...
```